# Pricing for using SQS within EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

If messages are both sent and received from different EC2 instances in the same region, there will be no cost right?
In other words, messages are only billed if it's coming from or going to non-EC2 instances/systems?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Amazon SQS Pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/) for details of SQS pricing.

It is charged as:

- Price per 1 Million Requests after Free Tier (Monthly)
- Plus data transfer

A **request** includes `SendMessage`, `ReceiveMessage`, `DeleteMessage`, etc.

The **Data Transfer** charge within a Region is free. For example, if requests come from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region as the Amazon SQS queue, there is no charge. The Data Transfer charge only applies for data going *out* of the cloud, eg to the Internet or to another Region.

As per the page:

> Data transferred between Amazon SQS and Amazon EC2 within a single region is free of charge (that is, $0.00 per GB). Data transferred between Amazon SQS and Amazon EC2 in different regions is charged at Internet Data Transfer rates on both sides of the transfer.

Comment: Applies both to ec2 and lambda